# Difference of HTTP Components, Restlet, Apache Mina and Netty

Tags: java, web-services, apache-mina, netty

I used HTTPComponents to implement a custom web server that access SQLite database. Requests are sent via TCP/IP and I am using REST concepts. By the way my frontend is HTML/jQuery. I know it will be a lot easier if I'll just create a servlet but I am restricted to just using apache http server.
I really don't get good performance in using HTTP Components.
Any suggestions please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear exactly what product or library you are referring to. You mention HttpComponents in one instance, but HTTP server in another, and you subject is about something completely different. Just in case you are talking about Apache HttpCore, which is a part of HttpComponents project, it is not known to have any major performance related issues. It actually performs reasonably well

http://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/HttpCoreBenchmark